# How can I get count of deleted rows

Tags: 7, database

How can I get count of deleted rows after `db_delete`?

```
db_delete('node')
  ->condition('uid', 1)
  ->execute();
```

something like

```
$count = db_delete('node')
  ->condition('uid', 1)
  ->execute()->columnCount();
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delete query will return a query object for all methods except ->execute(). Methods can be chained until the query has been assembled. Execute() completes the chain.

Try:

```
$count = db_delete('node')
  ->condition('uid', 1)
  ->execute();
```

Comment: thanks. yes. the task was simple. Looks I simply had some mistakes in conditions of my query.

Answer (score 2):

You can get count of deleted rows as follow:

```
db_delete('node')
  ->condition('uid', 1)
  ->execute();

$count = db_query('SELECT ROW_COUNT()')->fetchField();

print($count);
```

Answer (score 2):

Next expression works:

```
$count= db_delete('node')
  ->condition('uid', 1)
  ->execute();

dpm($count);
```

db_delete returns count of deleted rows after execution.